# sp_executesql does not return value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to be able to come up with list of columns for a given table.
When I run the following:

```
DECLARE @ColList Varchar(Max)
DECLARE @TabName varchar(100) = 'CT_CONF'

SELECT  @ColList =  CASE WHEN @ColList IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE @ColList + ',' END + column_name
                    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    where TABLE_NAME = @TabName
                      and DATA_TYPE not in ('xml','Text','Image','Geometry','Geography')
                      and COLUMN_NAME not in ('LAST_MODIFIED')
                    order by ordinal_position                   

select @ColList
```

I get the output I need, however, when I try to run sp_executesql as below, I get nothing back.

```
DECLARE @TabName varchar(100) = 'CT_CONF'

DECLARE @SQL NVarchar(Max)
DECLARE @ColList Varchar(Max)
Declare @Params nvarchar(Max)

SET @SQL = N'   
            select @ColList = CASE WHEN @ColList IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE @ColList + '','' END + column_name
                    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    where TABLE_NAME = ''@TabName ''
                      and DATA_TYPE not in (''xml'',''Text'',''Image'',''Geometry'',''Geography'')
                      and COLUMN_NAME not in (''LAST_MODIFIED'')
                    order by ordinal_position
            '

set @Params = N'@ColList varchar(Max) OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @ColList OUTPUT

select @ColList
```

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks,
Eugene

Comment: Do you have a table named `@SourceTable`?

Comment: My fault, it should read @TabName. I made a change. Still won't work.

Comment: You need to concatenate the table name into your dynamic query or pass it as a parameter. As it is now it is looking for a table named `@TabName` when it should be looking for `CT_CONF`.

Comment: Just tried ` where TABLE_NAME = ''CT_CONF'' `, still no go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
'...
    where TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TabName + '''
...'
```

Or (probably better):

```
'...
        where TABLE_NAME =  @TabName
...'
set @Params = N'@TabName varchar(100), @ColList varchar(Max) OUTPUT' 

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @TabName, @ColList OUTPUT
```

These are really just implementations of suggestions from @Mikael Eriksson in the comments.